# narrower catch and broader catch inside of it in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have a following nested try - catch in Java as you see below.
One of my concern is that

First ( and third ) catch is InterruptedException ( and Throwable ) and we have general Exception in this catch block.

1. I'm wondering this exception structure makes sense or not ( ie.
   narrower outside catch, and broader inside catch ). 
   Catch blocks don't throw an exception, it's just logging.
2. if this structure
   is not good, is there a better way?

   ```
   public void run() {
   try {

   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {    // narrower
       ....
       try {
           ...
       } catch (Exception e) {             // broader
           ...
       } finally {
           ...
       }
   } catch (ShutdownSignalException shutdownException) {
       try {

       } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

       }
   } catch (Throwable ex) {
       try {

       } catch (Exception e) {

       }

       try {

       } catch (Exception e) {

       } finally {

       }
   }}}
   ```

Comment: The answer depends entirely on whether you have statements where you have `...` that may throw the narrower exception. It *looks* highly suspect (not least because if you're doing that much error-recovery logic, it should probably be split into separate methods).

Comment: There is a dedicated code review forum on stackexchange that you might want to try first.